# I'm not able to pass value inside BaseException constructor. Why?

Tags: java, android, exception

**BaseException**

```
class BaseException(private val classname: String) : Exception() {

    override fun setStackTrace(stackTrace: Array<out StackTraceElement>) {
        val trace = arrayOf(StackTraceElement(classname, "methodNameOfExe", classname, 10))
        super.setStackTrace(trace)
    }
}
```

**TestClass**

```
{
....

    override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, viewType: Int) {
            try {
                setOnBindViewHolder(viewHolder, viewType)
            } catch (e: BaseException("Test")) { //compiler error for BaseException constructor
               ....
            }
        }

...
```

Compiler error is coming, if I'm trying to pass String arg

Comment: What is compile error saying? Can you share it?

Comment: @AlperDerya Solved it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not the correct way of doing it, you can't pass through parameters when assigning types.

take the following as example:

```
val foo : String
```

here, i'm specifying that my variable `foo` is of type String, right ? That's exactly what this statement is doing as well :

```
catch (e: Exception)
```

you're saying that `e` is of type `Exception`, you can't create a new instance here.

that means that you should change your code to be something like this:

```
catch (e: BaseException) {}
```

and then where you need to use this, you'd do something like:

```
throw BaseException("Test"))
```